# Can I show the Mission Control desktop number in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, mission-control

Spaces used to show the space number in the menu bar; I would glance at it regularly to see which space I was in (1, 2, 3, etc).

How do I get Mission Control to display the current desktop in the menu bar like that?

Comment: As this question is quite old I won't do a real answer but comment: I use *BitBar* (find at GitHub) to call a bash script that _ONLY_ calls an AppleScript in which the current background picture is compared to a stored list and accordingly its number "return"ed and thus very simply displayed as `[ 2 ]`, setting its refreshing rate by naming the bash script "desktop.3s.sh` for a 3 second interval. . . . . Extremely easy & pragmatic!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe the open source [WhichSpace](https://github.com/gechr/WhichSpace) project can do this:

> ## WhichSpace
>
> Have you ever forgotten which space is currently active on OS X (10.11+) and wanted a quick way to tell? Didn't think so... but I did!
>
> ### Screenshot
>
> [image: WhichSpace]

Comment: This open source project is by far the best solution I've found, if you want a simple number to ID the current Space. No bloated duplication of features like some other options.

Comment: To make WhichSpace start automatically when you log in, open System Preferences, Users & Groups, Login Items, and add WhichSpace to the list.

Comment: Interested programmers: this watches and reads the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist` to get workspace information. This bash command dumps the monitor information: `plutil -convert json -o /dev/stdout ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist`. essentially the program looks in `.SpacesDisplayConfiguration["Management Data"]["Monitors"]. `

Comment: this app shows wrong number for fullscreen app on macos v11

Comment: I was wondering if there is a solution for a multi-monitor setup. eg. show the active space per screen?

Answer (score 16):

I could not find any built-in feature for this, so I decided to use the backgrounds.

- I found a background image that I wanted, and made 8 copies of it.
- Then I wrote the numbers 1-8 on each of them, next to where the dock usually is.
- Then you press ctrl+1 to make sure you're in desktop 1, right click the background, and choose the image with 1 written on it.
- Then close down the system preference box (otherwise you end up changing only desktop one).
- Then press ctrl+2 and do right click again.

Not allowed to post screenshot :( to show how it looks.

Comment: can you upload the screenshot to imgur.com and post a link to it here?

Comment: Good idea, I upvoted so you might have enough rep for an image upload

Comment: +1. not a bad idea. I'm going to overlay numbers on the 4 corners of my background. Thanks for posting this...

Answer (score 11):

Found [SpaceId](https://github.com/dshnkao/SpaceId), a solution which I prefer over WhichSpace. It has options for viewing all created spaces (not just the current one) as well as multi-monitor and full-screen support. It also fixes some visual bugs WhichSpace suffers from. Works well on MacOS 12.0.1.

[image: Screenshot of SpaceID]

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I had the same issue. Turns out, all I really wanted was to instantly know what screen I am on.

I just accidentally "discovered" the obvious: if you 4-finger swipe up, everything zooms out. Across the top, all your desktops are shown and your current desktop is highlighted! (4-finger swipe down to go back to normal).

So this quick & easy approach solves things for me! Besides requiring much less work, it's also better than making custom numbered background images because I often have windows that entirely block my background. Now, I just swipe up, then back down and, in a split second, I know exactly where I am.

Posting here just in case it helps someone else...

Answer (score 2):

This problem now has a much more robust solution, thanks to [Total Spaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com).  This app brings back the old 2D grid of spaces and shows the space number in the menu bar.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution relies on code injection into Dock - which requires the turning off of some security features on El Capitan. It was a good solution in 2012, but not any more.

Comment: this is paid app.

Comment: TotalSpaces does not work on M1 Macs, and is basically discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

You may would like to use [SketchyBar](https://felixkratz.github.io/SketchyBar/features). It is really cool and popular. You can also customize it as you want.

[image]